# Show different content based on option class, not value

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a web page i have various forms like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
 
 <input type="text">

 <select name="a">
  <option class="hide-all">Choose</option>
  <option class="show-link">Show link</option>
  <option class="show-submit">1</option>
  <option class="show-submit">2</option>
 </select>

 <input class="hidden show-if-class-show-submit-selected" type="submit">Submit form</form>
 <a class="hidden show-if-class-show-link-selected" href="page.html">Link</a>

</form>
```

How can i show the submit button or the link based only on option class not on value optoin, i must use only class not ids....:). Thank you!

Comment: As you've not shown any attempt to solve this yourself, I'll simply say use the `change` event and read the `class` of the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `change` event of the `select` element. (*also add a class to identify the elements involved so you can hide them again once you change the option*)

```js
$(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var option = $(this).find(':selected'),
      relatedClass = option.attr('class');

    $(this).closest('form')
      .find('.select-target')
      .addClass('hidden')
      .filter('.' + relatedClass)
      .removeClass('hidden');
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="post">

  <input type="text" />

  <select name="a">
    <option class="hide-all">Choose</option>
    <option class="show-link">Show link</option>
    <option class="show-submit">1</option>
    <option class="show-submit">2</option>
  </select>

  <input class="hidden show-submit select-target" type="submit" value="Submit form">
  <a class="hidden show-link select-target" href="page.html">Link</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(){
    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    document.querySelector('.show-if-class-show-link-selected').style.display = selected.className === 'show-link' ? '' : 'none';
    document.querySelector('.show-if-class-show-submit-selected').style.display = selected.className === 'show-submit' ? '' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
 
 <input type="text">

 <select name="a">
  <option class="hide-all">Choose</option>
  <option class="show-link">Show link</option>
  <option class="show-submit">1</option>
  <option class="show-submit">2</option>
 </select>

 <input class="hidden show-if-class-show-submit-selected" type="submit">Submit form</form>
 <a class="hidden show-if-class-show-link-selected" href="page.html">Link</a>

</form>
```